# Adding a new node in the topology after the given time interval

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I am writing an algorithm for which I want to add new nodes in the topology after every 1 minute for 5 minutes. Initially the topology contains 5 nodes, so after 5 minutes it should have total 10 nodes. How can I implement this in the simulation script. Which behaviour will be best suited to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having the node being added after some time? If you just want simulate the nodes joining/leaving the network (like AUVs swimming into/out of a network range), you could have the nodes change their location using the `node.location` parameter and move them in/out of the network range using something like a `WakerBehavior`.